# Manipulating list of lists and dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a list of lists representing the keys in a dictionary. I wish to pickup the smaller key for each list in lists. For instance,

```
L1 = [['1_A','2_A'],['1_B','2_B']]
D1 = {'1_A': 0.22876, '2_A': 0.22382, '1_B': 0.2584, '2_B': 0.25373}

for li in L1:
    for ll in li:
        if ll in D1.keys():
            print "Value for %s is %s" %(ll,D1[ll])
        else:
            print "Values not found"
```

When I print it, I get:

```
Value for 1_A is 0.22876
Value for 2_A is 0.22382
Value for 1_B is 0.2584
Value for 2_B is 0.25373
```

The output I expect is `2_A`, `2_B` since both of them have smaller values compared to `1_A` and `1_B` respectively. Can anyone suggest how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not comparing the values anywhere.

```
L1 = [['1_A','2_A'],['1_B','2_B']]
D1 = {'1_A': 0.22876, '2_A': 0.22382, '1_B': 0.2584, '2_B': 0.25373}

template = "Value for {} is {}"

for i,j in L1:
    if D1[i] < D1[j]:
        print template.format(i,D1[i])
    else:
        print template.format(j,D1[j])
```

Comment: Hi, ~for i,j in L1~ works only when the element has two members.

Comment: To account for more variables in L1, I did the following: ~ for i in L1:
   for k in i:
        print("Value of k: ",k)
        for l in i:
            if l != k:
                print("Value of l: ",l)~ But I get the error, too many values to unpack. The output shows one value for k and two other values for l. Can you please give your suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

I found another simple answer !

```
L1 = [['1_A','2_A'],['1_B','2_B']]
D1 = {'1_A': 0.22876, '2_A': 0.22382, '1_B': 0.2584, '2_B': 0.25373}

for i in L1:
    val = (sorted(i, key=D1.get))[0]
    newlist.append(val)

"newlist = ['2_A', '2_B']"
```

A list comprehension version:

```
newlist = [sorted(i,key=D1.get)[0] for i in L1]
```

Thanks !

Comment: Forgot to mention that, this also works for different len of each element in list of lists !